# Can't Change subsubsection to runin with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I followed previous examples on here, but could not eliminate the newline after the subsubsection (I want it to runin just like paragraph does)

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalsize\itshape}{}{}{}[]

\begin{document}
\subsection{testing}
blah blah blah
\subsubsection{subtesting}\paragraph{further testing}blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: It *is* runin style, but `\paragraph` starts a new paragraph anyway.

Comment: How do I achieve them both on the same line? I want the subsection heading "subtesting" and then immediately on the same line in the paragraph style defined above "further testing"

Comment: I'm not sure *why* you'd want to do it.

Comment: Because that is the style dictated by the paper I am working on...

Comment: maybe you need \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} but i am not at my computer to check

Comment: @JM Then `\paragraph` is not the command you want to use. Define your own

Comment: @egreg Alright then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own command that calls `\paragraph` only when not immediately `\subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalsize\itshape}{}{}{}[]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\prg}[1]{%
  \if@noskipsec\textit{#1}\quad\else\paragraph{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\subsection{testing}
blah blah blah

\subsubsection{subtesting}
blah blah
\prg{further testing}blah blah blah

\subsubsection{subtesting}\prg{further testing}blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]